# Docker container not accessible after X minutes in AWS

Tags: linux, networking, amazon-web-services, docker

I have a docker container (from sonarqube image) running on AWS and it was not remotely accessible. I was able to access only through ssh.

To fix my problem, I need to run this command:

```
$ sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
```

The problem is that after some minutes (of after some event) this flag is reverted back to net.ipv4.ip_forward=0. Something is automatically adding a row in this file:

```
#-> grep net.ipv4.ip_forward /etc/sysctl.conf
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 0
```

Somebody knows what can be the cause? Maybe is some configuration on AWS?

Answer (score 0):

Have you check tuned and confirm wether this tuned might be overwriting your systemctl settings? This happened to me on several machines and swappiness

Answer (score 0):

When you run:

```
sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
```

the changes are not saved, they are temporarily written to /proc and will be lost if you restart the network.
You must edit `/etc/sysctl.conf` directly, delete the `net.ipv4.ip_forward = 0` line, keep the `net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1` line  and then run:

```
sysctl -p
```

Other possible causes:

- do you have `IPForward=no` in `/etc/systemd/network/50-containers.network` ?
- do you have `ip_forward=0` in `/etc/sysctl.d/ip_forward.conf`?
- are you using an EBS backed EC2 image? If not, the root device is not preserved across reboots
- is this EC2 instance started by an ELB? The ELB might decide to kill and start a new instance at any time, therefore changes to /proc that are not saved to disk are lost